# a True if statement that without reason is not executed

Tags: python

My statement has the following form:

```
if '&amp' in var_dictionary['key_name']:
    pass:
```

That statement never executed. Knowing that because of my input in some cases it should have executed, I used pycharm debugging. There, in a specific case where the statement 
`'&amp' in var_dictionary['key_name']` in the 'Evaluate' window was proven to be True, stepping into the next command, the enclosed in the if statement command was simply skipped. And it is skipped every time I tested my code. Is there an explanation? Actually I have overcame that problem using replace(), but knowing that the occurrences of '&' in my input are very few, I would prefer to use that 'if statement', than replace() method to be applied in every element of my input. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what happens when you remove the colon after `pass`?

Comment: do a print(var_dictionary['key_name']) and share with us one that you feel should have triggered the if statement.

Comment: How do you know it is doing nothing? I know that breakpoint on pass statement does not stop the execution. Maybe this make you think it does not insert the if body?

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the alleged incorrect skipping.

Comment: @LiorCohen I'm guessing it would throw a syntax error due to pass:

Comment: Finally when I placed the replace() method into the if statement, it was executed. I had the impression that I had used again 'pass' as a breakpoint, but as it seems I may be wrong. Thank you